# How do I set the tab size in the output window of Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tab-size

I want to match it to the tab size of notepad (8 characters). Default is 4, I believe.

Answer (score 6):

The simple way is to set the tab size for all types of files. Four spaces is indeed the default, but it's easily changed to your personal preference.

1. In Visual Studio, open the "Tools" menu and select "Options".
2. In the TreeView on the left, expand the "Text Editor" heading.
3. Underneath "Text Editor", expand the "All Languages" heading.
4. Underneath "All Languages", select the "Tabs" item.
5. In the textboxes on the right, fill in the tab size and indent size that you want to use.
   You can also determine whether to keep tabs or automatically replace them with spaces.

   [image]